# Protractor tests passing before page fully loaded

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

My protractor tests have started failing after updating my node_modules. The tests appear to start running before the page has even loaded:

```
Using the selenium server at http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
Spec started

Login
✓ should navigate to the homepage
✓ should display login form

Password > Forgot Password
✓ should go the forgot password form
✓ should not redirect user if email does not exist

Executed 4 of 4 specs SUCCESS in 0.025 sec.
Uncaught exception: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "[ng:test] no injector found for element argument to getTestability\nhttp://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/ng/test"
[launcher] Process exited with error code 1
```

The launched Google Chrome window is blank, but it has the right url (http://localhost:8081). However, if I do not run tests and instead just call `browser.get('/')`, the window navigates to my web app and the page loads as expected.

I suspect the tests are somehow running independent of the communication between protractor, selenium and Chrome and erroring asynchronously, somehow.

I am currently running the following versions:

- protractor: 2.5.1
- selenium-server-standalone: 2.47.1 (I have also tried with 2.46.0)
- chromedriver: latest version, installed using `webdriver-update`
- chrome: 52.0.2743.116

Comment: Does the same happen in Firefox? What if you turn on or off directConnect?

Comment: And Protractor 2.5.1? There is 4.0.4 already, why don't you upgrade?

Comment: Any errors in the browser's console?

Comment: Firefox does not connect at all. directConnect on and off has no effect for either chrome or firefox.

Comment: Using version 4 fixes the issue. Thanks :-)

Comment: @Joaquimd'Souza Sweet. You can add that as an answer and accept it yourself so others know the Q is resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @alecxe, upgrading to v4 fixed my issue.